# Launching authorization dialog while running one application

Tags: linux, gnome

In my application i need to write some files into Linux file system folder, which requires

super user access permission.

So, how can i invoke that dialog so that current user will have super user permission until

write operation finishes. I am using glib related APIs.

Regards,
Lenin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [GKSu](http://live.gnome.org/gksu) or the newer [PolicyKit](http://live.gnome.org/PolicyKit).

> GKSu is a library that provides a Gtk+ frontend to su and sudo. It supports login shells and preserving environment when acting as a su frontend. It is useful to menu items or other graphical programs that need to ask a user's password to run another program as another user.

Comment: i have solved writing to file system. But, when i enter wrong password i got the error in while calling gksu_run() method as under:                                                        GError *error;                                            state = gksu_run("cp '/home/MyHome/Desktop/newxml.xml' '/usr/doc/newxml.xml'",&error);

Comment: Actually after wrong pas word is entered, prompt is not called as in terminal, where i run the same command.

Answer (score 0):

Check out GKSu: http://www.nongnu.org/gksu/